# tough conditional

Tags: conditionals

My friend told me that she wanted to do something interesting tonight but she is too tired. I replied:

what would you like to have done? if you werent so tired?

This seems incorrect to me. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hello, Wes, and welcome to EL&U. This possibly POB, as it depends on culture, geography, register, etc. Personally, I would write, "'''what would you "have liked to do,..." The problem is, that you have not specified the "tone" and "meaning". There is a lot of difference between the 2.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I should just explain, I am a native English speaker (which makes this a little embarrassing that I'm having to ask!) I was asking in an informal way. I wanted to know: had she not been so tired, what she would have wanted to do. Does that clear it up a little? I think remarkl has explained it quite well so thanks for that. What is POB by the way?

Comment: Sorry for the jargon. I keep getting called out on that. Primarily Opinion Based (POB) Your question is a (another acronym) VTC "vote to close". We kinda require a minimum of research, and more context.

Comment: Unless you can identify why you think it's wrong, this is essentially a proofreading question—which is off-topic.

Comment: In casual speech you don't have to be so concerned with precise tense formation. You can say "What would you like to do if you weren't so tired?"